# How to get the following $token to work with my mail

Tags: php, html

I am trying to get the following to work but I have a parse syntax error of unexpected string. I think it could be my $token variable but the syntax look correct. I thought that you can have ".." around $token?

```
$htmlContent = "<h1>Update your temporary password!</h1>
<p>You are receiving this email because you have changed your password. 
Your temporary password is: ".$token." \n\n However, for security purposes,
please make sure that you change to a new password by clicking on the link 
here <a href=http://www.pianocourse101.com/includes/changepassword.php?email=".htmlspecialchars($mailTo)."&temporarypassword=".htmlspecialchars($token)>Click here to change your password</a>;</p>";
```

Comment: Is that a PHP variable? Are you parsing with javascript or something else? Welcome to Stack Overflow, by the way. Could you please provide a code sample for us?

Comment: Apologies.. I forgot to end the last variable with ."

Comment: The sample was there, but HTML gets filtered out unless you use the markdown for code (backticks for short code, 4 spaces for long code blocks). I edited your question for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a quote and a concat operator at `".htmlspecialchars($token)` **."** `>Click here to change your password</a>;</p>";`

If you use a code editor with syntax highlighting like [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) (Windows) or [Gedit](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit) (Windows & Mac) it's easier to spot those tiny coding mistakes.